# nginx => Serve two websites from one server block with sub-domain

Tags: nginx

I'd like to serve two applications from the same server through nginx. I'd like these applications to be available through a single domain name with sub-uris.

e.g.

`www.example.com` => should serve normal example site.
`www.example.com/blog` => blog.example.com (wordpress) site which is at different directory

Here, anything user requests from `/blog/...` should be served from blog site, but url should be `www.example.com/blog/...`

I have tried this.

```
server {
    root /web/servers/example/public;
    ...
    ...
    location /blog {
        proxy_pass         http://blog.example.com;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Other try was,

```
location /blog {
    alias /web/servers/blog/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
            #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            #allow 127.0.0.1;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            #fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

None of the options are working for /blog. Main site is working fine.

Could anybody please help me to solve the issue?

Comment: in `location /blog` change `alias` to `root`

Comment: I tried replacing `alias` to `root` but, it's not working. It is giving me `404` error.